# How to add SoapUI to SVN?

Tags: eclipse, tortoisesvn, repository, soapui

I am trying to include soapUI in the TortoiseSVN repository. Currently, I have Eclipse in TortoiseSVN, but I would like to add soapui in as well. My SoapUI project imports a .jar that is comprised of my java files on eclipse. 
How do I go about doing this ?

I have researched online which tells me to create a new repository in Eclipse using svn://svn.eviware.com/soapui/trunk/core, however this is the error that I get.

[image: Error upon creating a new Repository Location for SoapUI in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot I assume you want to get SoapUI source and build it right ?

SmartBear moved SoapUI's source from SVN to GitHub. You'll find the source [here](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui)

More info on the [official website](http://www.soapui.org/Developers-Corner/building-soapui-from-svn.html)